# Bad user name Apache

Tags: centos

When I try to start apache I get error:

```
AH00543: httpd: bad user name apache
```

I can also see that my apache user not exists in /etc/passwd

I also tried to uninstall apache, but then I get warning:

```
warning: group apache does not exist - using root
```

SELinux is also disabled.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: why don't you just create the user, or use a different user.

Comment: How did you install Apache?

Comment: I have installed Apache with the following command: yum install httpd.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by removing:

```
/etc/passwd.lock
/etc/group.lock
/etc/gshadow.lock
/etc/shadow.lock
```

Answer (score 1):

Or go to */etc/httpd/* directory, and open *httpd.conf* file, then edit `User` and `Group` values to `daemon`:

```
nano /etc/httpd/httpd.conf # or vi
```

Find and change:

```
User apache
Group apache
```

To

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

Comment: As per comment on Rafael's answer this will have major side effects on a SELinux based system using the targeted policy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it running

```
sudo adduser apache
```

Comment: On RHEL/Centos this is going to create a LOT of SELinux issues. On any flavour of linux it would be considered bad practice to create a service account using a non-service account UID.